# Add a vertical divider line programmatically

Tags: java, android, view, divider

I am able to easily place a horizontal line programmatically.

```
View view2 = new View(this);
view2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFC2BEBF);
relativelayout.addView(view2, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
```

I now cannot find a solution to make a similar line except make it vertical.  Again, this needs to be done all programmaticallly.  I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189790/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-line-in-table-layout) but the code they provided did not work for me.  The code supplied in the link can be found below.

```
view v = new View(this);
v.setLayoutParams(2,new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

It is so simple to make the horizontal line.  How can I get my vertical line to work?

Comment: Have you tried interchanging `LayoutParams`'s arguments? Like this: `relativelayout.addView(view2, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
relativelayout.addView(view2, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(2,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this exact code and it didn't work before I posted my opening post.  Anyways, this worked exactly like it should have!  Thank you!